# Read object with vector attribute from file c#

Tags: c#, object, vector

I have this class:

```
public class Student
{
private int[] note;//vector de note
        private DateTime dataInrolarii;
        private int nrRestante; 
        private readonly int nrMatricol; 
        private const string sex = "feminin"
        public static int anStudiu = 3; 

 public Student(string cnp, string nume, int nrMatricol, DateTime dataInrolarii, int nrRestante, int[] note) : base(cnp, nume)
        {
            this.nrMatricol = nrMatricol;
            this.dataInrolarii = Convert.ToDateTime(dataInrolarii);
            this.nrRestante = nrRestante;
            this.note = new int[note.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < note.Length; i++)
                this.note[i] = note[i];
        }
}
```

Of course, i have getters, setters, toString() overloaded and more.
I have a text file with this object :

```
2920118080023, George, 2, 12/09/2016, 4, 10 3 4
```

and I want to read from file and displat in a textBox the Students from file. but i don't really know how to do this with the vector note.

Here is that i wrote:

```
    private void button_CitireTXT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("citiretxt.txt");
        string linie = null;
        while ((linie = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {//oricare ar fi tipul unui atribut citit din fisier, ele sunt STRING acolo
                string cnp = linie.Trim().Split(',')[0];
                string nume = linie.Trim().Split(',')[1];
                int nrmat = Convert.ToInt32(linie.Trim().Split(',')[2]);
                string datainrolString = linie.Trim().Split(',')[3];
                DateTime datainrol = DateTime.Parse(datainrolString);
                int nrRest = Convert.ToInt32(linie.Trim().Split(',')[4]);

                string noteString = linie.Split(' ')[5];

                for(int i=0;i< noteString.Length;i++)
                {
                    noteString[i] = Convert.ToInt32(noteString[i]);

                string[] notesString
                }



                Student s = new Student(cnp, nume, nrmat, datainrol, nrRest, note);
                tb_CitireDinTxt.Text += s.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to read the vector NOTE from file? Thank you

UPDATE:

private void button_CitireTXT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("citiretxt.txt");
        string linie = null;
        while ((linie = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string cnp = linie.Trim().Split(',')[0];
                string nume = linie.Trim().Split(',')[1];
                int nrmat = Int32.Parse(linie.Trim().Split(',')[2]);
                string datainrolString = linie.Trim().Split(',')[3];
                DateTime datainrol = DateTime.Parse(datainrolString);
                int nrRest = Int32.Parse(linie.Trim().Split(',')[4]);

               int[] notes = Array.ConvertAll(linie.Split(',')[5].Split(' '), int.Parse);


                Student s1 = new Student(cnp, nume, nrmat, datainrol, nrRest, notes);

                tb_CitireDinTxt.Text += s1.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you checked my answer? Is that helpful?

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar yes, it worked well. I also changed some things. I will make an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Writing answer by considering, Vector(from C++) -> List(in C#).**

If following is your file content,

```
2920118080023, George, 2, 12/09/2016, 4, 10 3 4
```

Split by `,`. Then your string at 5th index will contain `10 3 4`. Now to convert it into array of integer use `Array.ConvertAll()` or you can convert it to List as well

Try bellowed code

```
//Converting into int array
int[] notes = Array.ConvertAll(linie.Split(',')[5].Split(' '), int.Parse)

//Converting into List<int>
List<int> notes= Array.ConvertAll(linie.Split(',')[5].Split(' '), int.Parse).ToList()
```

Instead of

```
string noteString = linie.Split(' ')[5];

for(int i=0;i< noteString.Length;i++)
     {
          noteString[i] = Convert.ToInt32(noteString[i]);

          string[] notesString
     }
```